# .remove() in Python list gives the output "None"

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of values and I need to remove a specific one, however I end up getting the output "None", instead of a new list without the removed element

```
my_list = [(1, (255, 0, 255)), (10, (125, 0, 125)), (20, (0, 255, 255)), (28, (255, 0, 0)), (31, (125, 0, 255))]
new_list = my_list.remove((1, (255, 0, 255)))
print(new_list)
```

the output I get: `None`

the output I would like: `[(10, (125, 0, 125)), (20, (0, 255, 255)), (28, (255, 0, 0)), (31, (125, 0, 255))]`

The problem might be in the way it is formatted, however I get these results from somewhere, I didn't choose to write it like this. In that case how do I reformat the list?

Comment: On what authority did you determine that `remove` returns anything other than `None`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`remove` function modifies a list but always returns `None`. You can do something like this:

```py
my_list = [(1, (255, 0, 255)), (10, (125, 0, 125)), (20, (0, 255, 255)), (28, (255, 0, 0)), (31, (125, 0, 255))]
my_list.remove((1, (255, 0, 255)))
print(my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the remove() method returns None, it is documented here

[https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#:~:text=You%20might%20have%20noticed%20that%20methods%20like%20insert%2C%20remove%20or%20sort%20that%20only%20modify%20the%20list%20have%20no%20return%20value%20printed%20%E2%80%93%20they%20return%20the%20default%20None.%201%20This%20is%20a%20design%20principle%20for%20all%20mutable%20data%20structures%20in%20Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#:%7E:text=You%20might%20have%20noticed%20that%20methods%20like%20insert%2C%20remove%20or%20sort%20that%20only%20modify%20the%20list%20have%20no%20return%20value%20printed%20%E2%80%93%20they%20return%20the%20default%20None.%201%20This%20is%20a%20design%20principle%20for%20all%20mutable%20data%20structures%20in%20Python.).